# I wish you bought me... vs I wish you would buy me

Tags: modal-verbs

I came across these sentences and cannot tell the difference.
What is the difference between these two sentences?

> I wish you bought me a car.
>
> I wish you would buy me a car.

Comment: Welcom to ELL. Thank you for your question. Please use the **[edit]** link (or click on 'edit'!) to tell us _where_ you "came across" these sentences. Is this from a lesson or exam? Also, please take the time to read our [**tour**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [**Help Center**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. They will help you to write a good question. We hope you will ask more of them!

Comment: It is difficult to wish for something that has already happened, right? *bought* is past tense...

Comment: @user3169 Well, you often wish for something that didn't occur, something that you'd like to change about the past or the present. *Bought* in that sentence suggests something unreal.

Answer (score -3):

Your first sentence is not correct because you are using the past tense of buy **(=bought)** to make a wish about the future.

The second sentence is **ok** because although **would** is a past tense modal verb we are allowed to use it to talk about a wish for the future.

Here is another example:

**I wish it would rain tomorrow.**

Another past tense modal that can be used to express a wish about the future is **could**  Here is another example:

**I wish you could help me with my exam tomorrow**.

I hope that helps a bit.

Some help from British Council website